# Discord.py Image download

Tags: python, discord.py

i made an ML model that predicts whether or not an image is gore, but im having trouble with the discord bot part. I dont know how to automatically download an image. any suggestions?

I've tried many tutorials but none have worked

Comment: Are you trying to download an image from a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message) event to automatically download images uploaded in channels where your bot has access:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    for attachement in message.attachments:
        if attachment.content_type.startswith("image"):
            # download the image content
            content = await attachment.read()
```